# New Azure Portal - Application Logging

Tags: azure

On the newly published Azure Portal, where do we find application logging (table storage) for web apps?
On the old version, there was a button on the right, which cannot be found in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

We can find application in new portal->Monitor-> Diagnostics logs, we need enable it first:
[image]

More information about streaming logs, refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-streaming-logs-and-console).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.